# How to clone an HTML block?

Tags: jquery, jquery-clone

I'm struggling with the Jquery clone. I can clone a single line of HTML, but I don't have a clue on how to clone a block.

I have this block:

```
<div class="item-name">
    <label for="id_form-0-name"></label>
    <select id="id_form-0-name" name="form-0-name"></select>
</div>
```

And I need to produce more two blocks, each time changing the attributes of the new block to reflect its position.

```
<div class="item-name">
    <label for="id_form-1-name"></label>
    <select id="id_form-1-name" name="form-1-name"></select>
</div>
<div class="item-name">
    <label for="id_form-2-name"></label>
    <select id="id_form-2-name" name="form-2-name"></select>
</div>
```

Any clue on what I've to do to obtain that output?

Comment: Please show your JS code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.item-name').clone().insertAfter('.item-name')
```

Source:

1) About `clone()` http://api.jquery.com/clone/
2) About `insertAfter` http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/

**FOR YOUR ADDITIONAL REQUEST**

Try something like this:

```
$clone = $('.item-name:last').clone();
for (i = 1; i < 999; i++) {
    if ($('.item-name select[id=id_form-'+i+'-name]').attr('id') != 'id_form-'+i+'-name') {
        $clone.find('select').attr('id', 'id_form-'+i+'-name');
        $clone.find('select').attr('name', 'form-'+i+'-name');
        $clone.find('label').attr('for', 'id_form-'+i+'-name');
        break;
    }
}
$clone.insertAfter('.item-name:last');
```

Comment: It is cloning. And how can I produce the new attribures for the "for", "id" and "name"? Best Regards,

Comment: you mean  you need to find the `eq` and change the attributes as well as clone the block

Comment: @André I have modified my answer. Try now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (cloning it twice):

```
$('.item-name:last').clone().insertAfter($('.item-name:last')).clone().insertAfter($('.item-name:last'));
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/popnoodles/uvVW4/1/)

So clone it and increment the attributes.
You can do it in one line but to make it easy to follow:

```
var clone=$('.item-name:last').clone();
clone.insertAfter('.item-name:last');
var attrs='id_form-' + clone.index() + '-name';
clone.find('label').attr('for', attrs);
clone.find('select').attr({id: attrs, name: attrs});
```